# Google Play Games Services(Web): Retrieves the Player resource error

Tags: google-play-games

I used APIs Explorer with request parameters：

```
playerId => me
```

Then I got response：

```
{ "error": { "code": 500, "message": null } }
```

Url： https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/players/get?hl=zh-TW

API Url： https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/playerId

Now our website can't get player id by this API. A user who logged in our website can't shop. What happened？

Comment: could it be a temporary outage on Google side?

Comment: was it working before but now suddenly doesnt?

Comment: it was working before, but it doesn't work for over 2 months.

Comment: My question is the same as 'Google API “games.players.get” returns 500' this question.